# Java simple log in \ register application

Tags: java

I just learned about hashmaps so I thought about making a little application that provide log in and register service. I got stuck while making it, and I didn't finish the login method.

Member.java -

```
public class Member {
private final String username;
private final String password;
private final String firstName;

private static final Map<String, String> loginMember = new HashMap<>();


public Member(String username, String password, String firstName) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return this.username + "";
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password + "";
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName + "";
}

public boolean isMemberExist(Member member){
    if(loginMember.containsKey(member.getUserName()) && loginMember.containsValue(member.getPassword())){
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No member in the list!");
    }
    return false;
}

public void register(Member member) {
    if(isMemberExist(member)) {
        System.out.println("This member is already exist!");
    } else {
        loginMember.put(member.getUsername(),member.getPassword());
    }
}
public void login(Member member){
    if(isMemberExist(member)) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + member.getFirstName());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No member with username " +member.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Main.java -

```
public class Main {
private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private static Member member = new Member("blabla","blabla","bla");
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean exitRequested = false;
    while(!exitRequested) {
        System.out.println("Press: " + "\n" +
                        "\r" + "1.Register" + "\n" +
                        "\r" + "2.Log in" + "\n" +
                        "\r" + "3.Exit.");
        int choice = sc.nextInt();
        switch (choice){
            case 1:
                register();
                break;

            case 2:
                login();
                break;

            case 3:
                exitRequested = true;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("?");
                break;
        }
    }

}
public static void register() {
    System.out.println("What's your first name?");
    String firstName = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter username");
    String username = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter password");
    String password = sc.next();
    Member newMember = new Member(username,password,firstName);
    member.register(newMember);
}

public static void login(){ // here I got stuck I seriously dont know how to continue...
    System.out.println("Username:");
    String username = sc.next();
    System.out.println("Password:");
    String password = sc.next();

}
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: Create your HashMap in your main() method and store your Member username as key and member object as value.. So its easy to validate or remove user using key.. To make it even more easier, override equals() and hashCode() method to avoid duplicate entries.

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is for finishing your code. How exactly are you stuck? What isn't working? What is it doing? What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the HashMap is in another class and your "login" is in the Main class. So from the main class you would need to access the HashMap from the Member class

I made the necessary changes in the code to make the HashMap accessible from another class. Also I deleted some of your conditionals because it is not working. I can probably solve it but it is not the question ("Login" is your question right?). So I tested the code and it is working fine. Register -> Login -> if Correct (terminate program) -- if not (login again).

Member.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Member {
private final String username;
private final String password;
private final String firstName;

private static final HashMap<String, String> loginMember = new HashMap<>();

//add a blank constructor so you can call this class for login purposes
public Member(){
    this.username = "";
    this.password = "";
    this.firstName = "";
}

public Member(String username, String password, String firstName) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

//method to access hashmap to another class
public HashMap<String, String> getMemberMap() {
     return loginMember;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return this.username + "";
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password + "";
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName + "";
}


//something wrong with this method here
public boolean isMemberExist(Member member){
    if(loginMember.containsKey(member.getUsername()) && loginMember.containsValue(member.getPassword())){
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No member in the list!");
    }
    return false;
}

//something also wrong here
public void register(Member member) {
        loginMember.put(member.getUsername(),member.getPassword());
}


public void login(Member member){
    if(isMemberExist(member)) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + member.getFirstName());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No member with username " +member.getUsername());
    }
}
}
```

Main.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
    private static final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Member member = new Member("blabla", "blabla", "bla");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean exitRequested = false;
        while (!exitRequested) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Press: " + "\n" + "\r" + "1.Register" + "\n" + "\r" + "2.Log in" + "\n" + "\r" + "3.Exit.");
            int choice = sc.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                register();
                break;

            case 2:
                login();
                break;

            case 3:
                exitRequested = true;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("?");
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void register() {
        System.out.println("What's your first name?");
        String firstName = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter username");
        String username = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter password");
        String password = sc.next();
        Member newMember = new Member(username, password, firstName);
        member.register(newMember);
        login(); //call login after registering
    }

    public static void login() { // here I got stuck I seriously dont know how to continue...
        System.out.println("Username:");
        String username = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Password:");
        String password = sc.next();

        Member x = new Member(); //call the member class
        HashMap<String, String> loginMember = x.getMemberMap(); //access the hashmap

        find(loginMember, username, password); 
    }
    
    //This is just for testing purposes.
    public static void find(HashMap<String, String> loginMember, String username, String password) {
        for (String i : loginMember.keySet()) {
            if (i.equals(username) && loginMember.get(i).equals(password)) {
                System.out.println("User is Found!");
                System.out.println("Program will now terminate");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("User Not Found. Login Again");
        login();
    }
}
```

You can probably work out the conditional statements on your own. I edited the register method so that I can register directly so that I can test the Login Function.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gerome Tahud.

What you were doing is just checking to see if the **username** and **password** exist. But if we have two users:

```
user1 (username1, password1, firstName1),
user2 = (username2, password2, firstName2)
```

in your HashMap and that a user informs:

```
username = username1,
password = password2
```

for registration, your function will say that this user exists, which is not the case, according to your logic.

Another thing that will produce the errors in your code is that, in **isMemberExist(...)** function you called **getUserName()** instead of **getUsername()**, Java doesn't interpret it the same way.

Comment: Hi, about the username it was my fault I edited the topic without watching my code, srry.